# Show Close- and Reopen-Votes on Vote Cast overview

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

On the overview, we only see up- and down-votes:

[image: Votes Cast]

If you click on *View more*, you see also close- and reopen-votes:

[image: Vote Casts - View More]

This feels incosistent. Could we have a summary of our Close- and Reopen-Votes please?

Comment: That is strange, it doesn't show close votes when I follow that link on my own profile. Almost feels like a bug ...?

Comment: @rene maybe some [configuration issue](http://imgur.com/a/WF4dn)?

Comment: Ah, that link only goes to your activity, where it remembers the last tab you were on. In that case the stat should also show deletion and undeletes for > 10K. Not sure how useful this is for other users to see.